# Systemd application executes but without correct file access

Tags: permissions, systemd

I'd like to have my application start automatically on boot. I'm using a systemd .service to do this, which is triggered by a complementary .path. The .path will only trigger the service when a number of directories and files exist. My .service and .path files below.

myApp.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=myApp systemd service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/
ExecStart="/home/root/myAppExec" -var1 var1Val

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

myApp.path:

```
[Unit]
Description=myApp systemd path

[Path]
PathExists=/home/root/myApp/
PathExists=/home/root/myApp/file1.ini
PathExists=/home/root/myApp/file2.ini
Unit=myApp.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The above appears to work, as the myAppExec executable is run with the assigned arguments. The issue I'm having, is that the application doesn't have access to any of the required files; all ini-based variables (read from file1.ini and file2.ini) are initialised as empty.

If I run the application directly (i.e. `./myAppExec -var1 var1Val`) the application works perfectly. I've checked the permissions on the required files, and provided systemd is executing the application as 'root' (as specified in .service), the application should have the required permissions.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you service is started too quickly, when `file1.ini` has been created but not yet written into. Try adding, say, `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 10` to the service to see.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had tried exactly that but unfortunately without success. In the end I found that I made use of the $HOME environment variable in the path definition for the .ini files in the application, which should have worked fine given my 'root' access. However, when I swapped $HOME with /home/root, the application worked perfectly. I've removed all instances of $HOME and now everything boots and runs as expected.